# Changes (subtle or not) in a database schema that break applications

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, schema

Besides the obvious, removing a column, renaming a column/table, dropping a table/schema what would be a list of changes in a database schema that could potentially break applications using it?
Would it be possible to give also some concrete examples?

Comment: This question is way too wide, but since virtually every schema change is visible to applications it follows that any schema change can break an application.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that changes the *logical* state of the database could potentially break code that depends on it. For example changes to data types, keys or integrity constraints could break business logic that requires data of a certain type or which assumes certain constraints apply.

Regrettably, many modern SQL DBMSs compromise physical data independence such that the important distinction between the syntax used to define logical features and that used for physical features is blurred or lost altogether. For example the index definition syntax may also be used to define key constraints (there is no such index syntax in ISO standard SQL).

The fact that DBMSs don't always make a clear distinction between logical and physical concerns probably explains the need for this question to be asked at all. It ought to be an extremely easy question to answer but poor design decisions by DBMS vendors have made things much more complicated than they need to be. The only way to answer the question therefore is to understand database principles thoroughly and then to know your software so that you can properly distinguish the logical and physical features of the DBMS you are using.

Comment: What do you mean with "*index definition syntax may also be used to define key constraints*". Indexes are defined using `create index` and a primary/foreign key is defined using `alter table`

Comment: @horse, Yes but in many versions of SQL you can use the UNIQUE keyword as part of the index definition to create a uniqueness constraint on the indexed columns, i.e. a key constraint.